# Queue mode in HPC Pack 2016 can scale up?

Tags: hpc

I'm working on a project where we need to execute a lot of jobs (say 60000 jobs) each time in HPC cluster.

From HPC documentation, i noticed HPC has 2 mode
- Queued mode: tart jobs in queue order, and attempt to allocate the maximum requested resources to running jobs.
- Balanced mode: Attempt to start all incoming jobs as soon as possible at their minimum resource requirements
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/high-performance-computing/understanding-policy-configuration?view=hpc16-ps

But i'm not sure about tolerance of this balance mode in HPC. Does it can scale like other queue service like SQS in AWS or Queue Storage in Azure?

Answer (score 0):

Queue mode and balance mode are referring to the scheduling policy. There is no real queue included.
Basically, in Queue mode, your jobs run in a FIFO manner. If the next job needs more cores then currently available, it waits despite the fact that there are available resources. While in Balance mode, HPC Pack tries to run as many jobs as possible at the same time and makes the best effort to ensure they use the same amount of resources., to maximize the resource usage.
Both two policies will not effect scale target of the cluster.